# JS: default text swap with live new element added

Tags: javascript, jquery, live

So for default text swapping on input (or other type of el) I have this snippet

```
    <input class="js_text_swap" type="text" value="Enter your email" />
```

```
    if($('.js_text_swap').length > 0) {
        $('.js_text_swap').each(function() {
            var that = $(this),
                value = that.val(); // remembering the default value

            that.focusin(function() {
                if(that.val() === value) {
                    that.val('');
                }
            });
            that.focusout(function() {
                if(that.val() === '') {
                    that.val(value);
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

---

So my questions are: 
1) **does anybody has a better solution for this?** 
2) **does anyone know how to make this work with live added elements** (added with js after page has loaded)?

Thanks

Comment: `added with js after page has loaded` ajax or dynamically created?

Answer (score 1):

Jap!

**HTML**

```
<input placeholder="Click..." class="text" type="text">
```

**CSS**

```
.text{color:#aaa}
.text.focus{color:#444}
```

**JS**

```
$("input[placeholder]").each(function() {
    var placeholder = $(this).attr("placeholder");

    $(this).val(placeholder).focus(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == placeholder) {
            $(this).val("").addClass('focus');
        }
    }).blur(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === "") {
            $(this).val(placeholder).removeClass('focus');
        }
    });
});
```

http://yckart.com/jquery-simple-placeholder/

**UPDATE**

To make it work with ajax or similar you need to convert it into a "plugin" and call it after your succesed ajax request (or after dynamically crap creating).

Something like this (very simple example):

```
jQuery.fn.placeholder = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var placeholder = $(this).attr("placeholder");

        $(this).val(placeholder).focus(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == placeholder) {
                $(this).val("").addClass('focus');
            }
        }).blur(function() {
            if ($(this).val() === "") {
                $(this).val(placeholder).removeClass('focus');
            }
        });
    });
};

$("input:text, textarea").placeholder();

$("button").on("click", function() {
    $(this).before('<input type="text" placeholder="default value" />');
    $("input:text, textarea").placeholder();
});
```

[demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/n5pUr/)

Comment: `added with js after page has loaded` Ajax or what?

Comment: this method is the same with mine (you have placeholder instead of value).